# How to upgrade a react native bare expo?

Tags: react-native, react-native-upgrade

We have a bare Expo react native project. It is currently using react native version 0.64 and we want to upgrade it to latest stable build. I'm new to the project and react native.

I was looking at the upgrade guide at https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading which talks about Expo vs. react native projects. What I'm confused about is which one to use here? since our is a `bare Expo` project? Any pointers on how to upgrade and tackle conflict along the way would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: We haven't upgraded our app, so take it with what its worth is. On my local system, I did upgrade the version as a POC using the upgrade helper available at: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/